Thunar custom action - generate full path and filename
This is a thunar custom action. I am trying to get it to show the full pathname AND filename of a highlighted file. This is not working.
readlink -f %f > filename_path.txt && geany filename.txt_path && rm filename_fath.txt

This gives the filename ONLY of a highlighted file.
basename %f > filename.txt && geany filename.txt && rm filename.txt

readlink from a terminal does give the full path and filename.

filename_path.txt, filename.txt_path, and filename_fath.txt? Did you get the aame thing wrong in two different ways in one command?

@muru Here is the answer. readlink -f %f > filename_path.txt && geany filename_path.txt && rm filename_path.txt I get the impression that very few folks user Thunar as their file manager.

I use Thunar as my file manager in Ubuntu 24.04. Files in my Ubuntu 24.04 lagged so much that it was unusable, and I never knew after I copy/pasted in Files that the file(s) actually got pasted.

@karel 11 I use  Ubuntu_Mate which is very similar to Ubuntu.  Give me more details and I will try to help you.

Let's say I'm updating the files in 100 or more directories, and I have to make an individual decision each time about which files need to be updated. I try to copy paste five times, ten times but nothing happens. Finally I think I've updated the directory, but I haven't. The result is I can't update my directories. I gave up at that point and installed Thunar. Problem solved. Before that I wrote my own file manager in Python just to solve that problem, but its GUI interface was too awkward and clumsy to do big jobs quickly.
